# Kafka Consumer architecture design: java plugin or external client

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, apache-kafka, consumer

I'm coding a solution for a data consumer to a kafka cluster (using dockers for kafka), but I still have to decide how to code it:

1. In the native language Kafka is developed: java, in which the official site and git repo provides examples, https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples
2. In another Client provided in another language, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients, e.g. Node.js

The point is that I know how to code a solution in both languages, but I have to decide in which one having to take into account:

- Real performance consuming kafka messages without making bottle necks. (My first impression is that coding everthing in the same core language Kafka is build will reduce overload), but I'm not really sure about this.
- In terms of designing of the solution (to keep language, code style consistency, and extensibility). The whole web interface, the rest service and also data persistency is developed in Node.js and clients are in javascript / HTML5.

This is for a ubuntu server, on a full dockerized environment, I use Node.js as a core language for web services and connecting modules. I'm still not tunning the kafka client, but using the default options:

### Java (using a KafkaConsumer)

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
... 
props = ...
KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
```

### Node.js (using kafka-node npm lib)

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
...
client = ....
var consumer = new kafka.Consumer( client, [{ topic: 'topicVehicle' }], { autoCommit: true });
```

I have to deal with the problem of maintaining the code at various layers in various languages (java, nodejs... probably python) and I'm wondering which is the more proper solution.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? It's not clear why you're needing more than one language, but node is popular in web and python is popular in data science. Java has Kafka Streams... so each have their tradeoffs

Comment: Node is used for the web app, the rest services, and multi-tier infrastructure (use redis, and mongodb for persistence). The Kafka is fed from a number of sensors and in the server side I have to set a consumer to feed the database... I plan to use more than one Kafka broker in parallel to handle the data.

Comment: My question is more about if coding a consumer in java as Kafka jar extension represents a real advantage or not. The alternative is using for example Node with a Kafka wrapper to code a consumer...

Comment: I would suggest using Kafka Connect to feed a database. Kafka Connect runs outside of a broker... Your producer code could be written in any language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take is that you would not want to create your Kafka consumer as a Kafka plugin for a few reasons:

- the main reason: creating standalone consumer allows you to scale it out and in based on the load, as needed, by adding or removing consumer instances for the same consumer group, letting Kafka re-distribute available partitions for processing among those consumer instances

other reasons:

- plugin is something that usually extends functionality of whatever you are writing the plugin for - Kafka in this case
- the biggest advantage of Kafka as a distributed message system is that you can have many independent consumers each doing their own thing, coming and going as they need to
- creation and deployment of those consumers should not be coupled with the deployment of Kafka (or its plugins) - you should be able to add/remove consumers with no dependencies on Kafka itself

Now, if you are developing some new type of Connector or another consumer that is really intended to be more like a framework/tool that will be used by other consumers/producers - it would make sense to develop it as a plugin for Kafka

Comment: After evaluating the different options, I will take your advice considering that decoupling prevails over performance as you can enhance performance later with parallelisim.Finally I opted for a Apache Flume for load of data.

Comment: good luck! we also use Flume as a data collection tier - works great